# Dropdown button with accordion not closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I followed the below post which helped in creating the `dropdown accordion`.

[Twitter Bootstrap: How to create a dropdown button with an accordion inside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323656/twitter-bootstrap-how-to-create-a-dropdown-button-with-an-accordion-inside-it)

However the dropdown doesn't close back and behave normally when I execute a `javascript` function from any of its `<a>` tags.

Updated fiddle with the issue.

[jsFiddle with Bootstrap example code](http://www.bootply.com/e2DOP8Zywl)

Comment: Everything works fine for me. Please can you give more details about your problem?

Comment: hold on, need to update the question.

Comment: sorry wrong fiddle, one moment please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.bootply.com/rbuS0mHLvd

check out this link if it will help.
If not then please explain the problem in detail with this code relevant to your code.
Basically i have removed the data-toggle=collapse as it will add the "in" class to your dropdown by which the dropdown is opened untill the class "in" is removed.

Comment: let me try this once.

Comment: i would need the `data-toggle=collapse` since if I remove it, the dropdown will always close. In the fiddle, try removing the `data-toggle` for Unit 2, it wont let me access the inner `<a>` tags.

Comment: actually i have removed it already from UNIT1 and for your code i dont think you have to remove the data-toggle=collapse for UNIT2.

Comment: if you really dont want to change your code then simply try this code in which i have removed the "open" class using jquery. As "open" class is responsible to open a dropdown.http://www.bootply.com/9A9crxSKJy

Comment: it works rather fine in chrome bootply, but with ie now the problem is that the accordion doesn't toggle properly. [Updated Fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/S2nU9Tu8nK)