# Bootstrap dropdown with submenu thats clickable and expandable

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I am trying to build bootstrap dropdown in which submenu can be expandable on click, I have snapshot attached with this question please check, I am not able to find anything like this on google so I am posting this question. Can anyone please provide me working css or jsfiddle for this? Here's what I've tried so far... ([**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2qw5j97r/))

[[image]]

```css
.dropdown-menu li {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #ccc;
}

.dropdown-menu li:last-child {
  border: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu li i {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.dropdown-menu li a {
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Export
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
    <li>
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i> 
      <a href="#">
        
        <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> Excel
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i> 
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-file-word-o"></i> Word</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i> 
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-o"></i> JSON</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: link to fiddle does not work

Comment: updated please check

Comment: @לבנימלכה updated fiddle link please check

Comment: i will give u one plus upvote too if you give me this

Comment: what you want exactly? `fa-file-word-o` chang on click?

Comment: use collapse inside dropdown
:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323656/twitter-bootstrap-how-to-create-a-dropdown-button-with-an-accordion-inside-it