# Bootstrap 4: How to create a dropdown menu with an accordion inside it?

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4, accordion

I am actually facing some problems to get an bootstrap accordion working inside a dropdown menu.
I googled a lot and also find some StackOverflow threads here, but they are several years old and depending on bootstrap 3 or bootstrap 2.
Like this one here: [Twitter Bootstrap: How to create a dropdown button with an accordion inside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323656/twitter-bootstrap-how-to-create-a-dropdown-button-with-an-accordion-inside-it/54416554#54416554)

Can anybody help me here or have a solution for a working accordion inside a bootstrap dropdown menu.

```xml
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item mega-dropdown-menu">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Test</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
        <nav class="navbar">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria- controls="collapseExample">Accordion</a>
              <div id="collapseExample" class="collapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-link">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Accordion Link 1</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-link">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Accordion Link 2</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 13):

The trick to keeping the Navbar dropdown open on click is to use a `<form>` tag. Therefore if you place the accordion inside a `<form>` it will work as desired.

```xml
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <form class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
          <div>
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
              Item #1
            </a>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse px-3 show" data-parent="#accordionExample">
              Collapse 1 content
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
              Item #2
            </a>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse px-3" data-parent="#accordionExample">
              Collapse 2 content...
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
              Item #3
            </a>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse px-3" data-parent="#accordionExample">
              Collapse 3 content...
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/F8iQy0MeLa

Comment: Could you provide a workaround for Bootstrap 5?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
// Prevent dropdown to be closed when we click on an accordion link
$('.dropdown-accordion').on('click', 'a[data-toggle="collapse"]', function (event) {
  $($(this).attr('href')).collapse('toggle');
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">                                        
  <div class="dropdown dropdown-accordion">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown
    </button>
 
    <div id="accordion" class="dropdown-menu">
    <div class="card dropdown-item">
      <div class="card-header">
        <a class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
           Item #1
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card dropdown-item">
      <div class="card-header">
        <a class="collapsed card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo">
        Item #2
      </a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card dropdown-item">
      <div class="card-header">
        <a class="collapsed card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree">
           Item #3
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not 100% working. You can't close accordion when click again.
Have a look at this codepen -> https://codepen.io/atcraigwatson/pen/yNGmEm
This one is working pretty well, but sadly not with Bootstrap 4 markup.
So what i need is the same behaviour, but within Bootsrap 4