# Bootstrap dropdown inside accordion

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

I have an Accordion which has a header, inside which I need to place a dropdown menu. I've tried fiddling with the z-index thinking it was a stacking issue to no avail. I've reproduced the issue with a minimal sample at https://www.bootply.com/53bH05eQlf

Is there any way to get the dropdown menu to display correctly?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">Blah</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">Blah</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">Blah
    <div class="dropdown text-center show border-info border rounded menu-button float-left">
                <a class="btn p-0 dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="some-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="fa fa-bars"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="some-dropdown">
                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Hidden behind the card!</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">Blah</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">Blah</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try adding  `style="overflow: visible"` to the card div which contains the dropdown.
That is, replace `<div class="card">` on line 8 with `<div class="card" style="overflow: visible">` in the bootply example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54416875/bootstrap-4-how-to-create-a-dropdown-menu-with-an-accordion-inside-it

Comment: @rahulpsd18 Amazing, I tried so many combinations, one line fixed it. Thanks! If you post it as an answer instead of a comment I'll give you the brownie points. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `style="overflow: visible"` to the card div which contains the dropdown will solve the issue.

That is, for the [bootply](https://www.bootply.com/53bH05eQlf) example replace `<div class="card">` on line 8 with `<div class="card" style="overflow: visible">`.