# How to find multiple div ID in JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, navigation

I'm creating a dropdown accordion style in bootstrap 4 and found this useful solution using JavaScript in stack overflow ([Twitter Bootstrap: How to create a dropdown button with an accordion inside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323656/twitter-bootstrap-how-to-create-a-dropdown-button-with-an-accordion-inside-it/54416554#54416554)). I modified the script to suit my website navigation style but I got stuck on how to make the JavaScript find not only ID: accordion but also ID: accordion1 and so on. Thus, when I navigate out of the menu, the accordion that open will automatically hide. Currently, the script can only hide the first panel which is ID: accordion. For this project, I can't use form tag as described in [Bootstrap 4: How to create a dropdown menu with an accordion inside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54416875/bootstrap-4-how-to-create-a-dropdown-menu-with-an-accordion-inside-it). Sample on [Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/p/x24UXGrLdu)

Also, how do I make the accordion panels open in multiples.

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown dropdown-accordion " data-accordion="#accordion">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        ONBOARDING
                        </a>

                        <div class="dropdown-menu ">
                            <div class="accordion" id="accordion">
                                <div>
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank">
                        Item 01
                            </a>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        Item 02
                        </a>
                                    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                                        <div> <a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank">
                                        Item 02A</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div> <a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank">
                            Item 02B
                                </a></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item dropdown dropdown-accordion " data-accordion="#accordion">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            OFFBOARDING
                        </a>

                        <div class="dropdown-menu ">
                            <div class="accordion" id="accordion1">
                                <div>
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank">
                        Item 01
                            </a>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapsetwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapsetwo">
                        Item 02
                        </a>
                                    <div id="collapsetwo" class="collapse px-3" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                                        <div> <a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank">
                            Item 02A
                                </a></div>
                                        <div> <a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank">
                            Item 02B
                                </a></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

    <script>
        $('.dropdown-accordion').on('show.bs.dropdown', function(event) {
            var accordion = $(this).find($(this).data('accordion'));
            accordion.find('.show').collapse('hide');
        });
$('.dropdown-accordion').on('click', 'a[data-toggle="collapse"]', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        $($(this).data('parent')).find('.collapse.show').collapse('hide');
        $($(this).attr('href')).collapse('show');
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: (Imho) Ids that differ only by the number at the end shouldn't be ids. Use a class instead.

Comment: Hi, at the moment  your HTML is not 'legal' with a couple of infelicities (e.g. duplicate ids). You might like to put it through the W3C validator. It'll make life easier.

Answer (score 0):

According to your script, you really are just hiding the div with id='accordion'. If you want to hide them all, you have to know the nr of accordions you have, and iterate through all of them.

```
    <script>
        $('.dropdown-accordion').on('show.bs.dropdown', function(event) {
            for(var i = 0; i < nrAccordions; i++)
            {
               var accordion = $(this).find($(this).data('accordion'+i));
               accordion.find('.show').collapse('hide');
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: what's nr? I've to give each accordion a different ID such as ID="accordion" and next panel is ID="accordion1".

Comment: nrAccordions is the nr of accordions you have on your page. You must give this variable a value before you run the loop

Comment: I'm blur..just change the data accordion will do. however, how do I make the accordion panels open in multiples for my navigation menu? here's sample https://www.codeply.com/p/x24UXGrLdu