# How to build a collapsible options inside a dropdown with plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropdown

I am trying to build a custom drop-down having collapsible options.
Each option inside the drop-down will have sub options which when selected will give me the value.

On an abstract, the drop-down should look like below:

[image]

Considering above idea, I have tried my approach through a fiddle.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.main-div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 180px;
  cursor:pointer;
   border: 1px solid salmon;
}

.inner-div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 210px;
  top: 58px;
  left: 8px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid salmon;
}
.inner-div > ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid salmon;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.inner-div > ul > span {
  display: inline;
}
.inner-div .acc-input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.inner-div .acc-input:checked ~ .acc-sub-cat {
  display: block;
}
.inner-div .acc-sub-cat {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div" onclick="myFunction()"> Select Items
</div>

<div class="inner-div" id="myDIV">
 <ul>
  <li>
   <input class="acc-input" type="checkbox" id="group-1">
   <label for="group-1"><span>Group 1</span></label>
   <ul class="acc-sub-cat">
    <li><a><span>Item 1</span></a></li>
    <li><a><span>Item 2</span></a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

But my snippet does not resemble the way I need it and I am not much experienced in CSS.
Can anyone help me to arrive at the desired figure with smooth CSS, please?

PS: I am not using jquery

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20325486/3995126 Please check this question

Comment: Hi Kevin, I am not willing to using jquery and moreover the state seems not preserving.

Comment: You could use the `<details>` HTML element. You don't need JS then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrited your code a lot according to your picture. Please, take a look.

You can remove `.active` from `.drop-box` so the menu will be collapsed at a start.

Added `.drop-box` around button and menu elements, with `position: relative;` so your dropdown menu with `position: absolute;` will depends on the parent position.

`.drop-button:after, .link:before` these are arrows, they they are rotating on `.active` class, as you can see.

**UPDATED**

Now the JS supports clicking outside of the element `drop-box` and closing it (removes `.active`). Although you can add multiple `.drop-box` element with structure like in my example, and they all will work separately.

```js
for (let dropbox of document.querySelectorAll('.drop-box')) {
  let dropButton = dropbox.querySelector(".drop-button");
  let dropMenu = dropbox.querySelector(".drop-menu");

  document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    let target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (target !== dropbox && !isChildOf(target, dropbox)) {
      dropbox.classList.remove("active");
    }
  }, false);

  function isChildOf(child, parent) {
    if (child.parentNode === parent) {
      return true;
    } else if (child.parentNode === null) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return isChildOf(child.parentNode, parent);
    }
  }

  dropButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    dropbox.classList.toggle("active");
    for (let link of dropMenu.querySelectorAll('.link')) {
      link.classList.remove("active");
    }    
  }, false);

  let xx = 0;
  for (let link of dropMenu.querySelectorAll('.link')) {
    (function(index){
      link.addEventListener("click", function() {
        let yy = 0;
        for (let links of dropMenu.querySelectorAll('.link')) {
          if (index !== yy) {
            links.classList.remove("active");
          }          
          yy++
        }
        this.classList.toggle("active");
      })
    })(xx);
    xx++;
  }

}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.drop-box {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.drop-button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
}

.drop-button:after,
.link:before {
  content: '';
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 3px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.drop-box.active .drop-button:after,
.link.active:before {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.drop-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 210px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
}

.drop-box.active .drop-menu {
  display: block;
}

.drop-menu .link {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.drop-menu .box {
  display: none;
  padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
}

.drop-menu .link.active+.box {
  display: block;
}

.drop-menu .box label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="drop-box active">
  <div class="drop-button">Select Items 1</div>
  <div class="drop-menu">
    <div class="link-box">
      <div class="link">Group 1</div>
      <div class="box">
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="box-1"><span>Box 1</span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="box-2"><span>Box 2</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="link-box">
      <div class="link">Group 2</div>
      <div class="box">
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="box-3"><span>Box 3</span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="box-4"><span>Box 4</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="drop-box">
  <div class="drop-button">Select Items 2</div>
  <div class="drop-menu ">
    <div class="link-box">
      <div class="link">Group 3</div>
      <div class="box">
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="box-5"><span>Box 5</span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="box-6"><span>Box 6</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="link-box">
      <div class="link">Group 4</div>
      <div class="box">
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="box-7"><span>Box 7</span></label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="box-8"><span>Box 8</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you need some explanations or improvements - just tell.

Comment: Actually, we have missed on thing here, the dropdown closes only when clicked on select items, but ideally we should also close it when it is clicked anywhere out of the dropdown

Comment: Also can it be modified like only one group should be open at a time and others should be collapsed??

Comment: Thank you for helping to make my answer better :) Totally rewrite code, made it shorter, more readable and easier to implement. Now with multi-dpropdowns support.